# Targeting a class applied to a div that has multiple classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose I have a few classes applied to a div like this:

```
<div class="classA classB classC">...</div>
```

In my CSS, I want to target and write styles for those `classC` that have `classB` applied to the same div as well.

If I use this:

```
.classB .classC {...}
```

This will only work if there is another child div, and is not what I want.

So, how can I target those `classC` that has `classB` applied to the same div?

Comment: Just remove the space between them, as that means "*descendant*." I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/490141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack them. Like so.

```
div.classA.classB.classC
```

This would work with IDs too, even though it is less applicable.

```
div#unique-1.classA.classB
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `div.classC.classB` as a selector

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
.classB.classC { }
```

No spaces between the classes will target all elements with both.